# Custom SQL query on wp_users with the addition of wp_usermeta

Tags: search, user-meta

I am trying to query a list of user id's in WordPress using SQL IN() with the addition of them having a meta_value value of "Yes" on the meta_key "is_registered" in the wp_usermeta table but I can't seem to get this to work. It just returns 0 results. If I use just the IN() with the array of ID's, it works fine.

Here is what I am using:

```
SELECT DISTINCT wp_users.ID FROM wp_users LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta ON ( wp_users.ID = wp_usermeta.user_id ) WHERE wp_users.ID IN(23,643,574,617,26) AND wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'is_registered' AND wp_usermeta.meta_value = 'Yes'
```

This must be SQL. I can't use WP_User_Query() as it's for a personal project of mine whereby I'd like to use SQL.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here as I've been racking my brain with it for what feels like forever now!

Answer (score 0):

I'd simply go for [`WP_User_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query) for this:

```
$args = [
  'meta_key'   => 'is_registered',
  'meta_value' => 'Yes',
  'fields'     => 'ID',
];

$user_query = new WP_User_Query($args);
```

Comment: This is actually a little dev project for myself and I am editing the WP_User_Query code through wp-includes/class-wp-user-query.php so I can understand it better so this solution will not work for me. It must be SQL. Thanks though.

Comment: @mcmaster.1986 – OK, then please update your question and add that little bit of extra info. Thanks

Comment: @mcmaster.1986 your query works, although it only will return User ID.  However, the users IN() must not have the meta key and value you specify.  If you remove your `IN()` clause does it return any results?

Comment: @HowardE okay well this is interesting as when I remove the IN() clause, it doesn't return anything when infact it should.Massive head scratcher this one!

Comment: @mcmaster.1986 you should double check your meta_key and values are correct then.  Without the IN function, you're just selecting all users where the meta_key is what you want.